# How to generate subnet mask for IP Address in Java?

Tags: java, ip-address, mask

I am sending a mail in java by using **mail.jar**. In that I am giving a URL to perform some action.

In the URL I am giving the actual **IP Address**. But I found that giving IP address is not secure.

So I want to **generate subnet mask** or something like that to secure the **IP Address**.

So Please help me to **generate subnet mask for IP Address in Java.**

Thank You

Comment: An example of what you have and what you're after would help.

Comment: I have IP Address 123.456.789.111, so I am expecting something like demo.example.com for my IP Address

Comment: `123.456.789.111` lol

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compute the subnet mask from the IP address. You can guess, but that guess may be wrong. I don't see how a subnet mask would “secure” an address in any way, or how an IP address would be less secure than a host name. What kind of security do you have in mind here?

So for the question as it currently reads, the answer is:
**That's impossible, but why should you want to do that anyway?**

Comment: Thanks MvG for your reply. I mean to secure IP Address in the way instead of giving IP number like '123.456.789.000' we should give like 'demo.example.com'

Comment: So it is not a *netmask* which you are looking for, but a *host name* instead. The task you try to accomplish here is usually called *reverse DNS*, and ways to address it in Java have already been [discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7097849/1468366). If there is a specific question you want to ask about reverse DNS, I suggest you do so in a new question, instead of editing this one here, as this is not an interactive chat site here.

Comment: Ok sorry I asked it in reverse, bcoz I dont hv much knowledge of Networking. I'll try with your link